# WebView link highlighting occurs on some devices, not on others

Tags: android, android-webview

Since feedback on links being clicked is important, I want this to happen on all devices. I tried setting `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` and `-webkit-focus-ring-color` in CSS but it has no effect on my 4.0.4 device. Several of my testers have reported that it works on their devices, so it seems to be a device-specific issue. How might I go about forcing the WebView to highlight, preferably (but not required) in a manner that's customizable by CSS in the header?

An example page that my app might load: http://pastebin.com/UQCVhZEX